# Is this pop() method for linked list in JavaScript correct? It works but I'm curious that if I use the correct method or not

Tags: javascript, class, data-structures, linked-list

```
pop(){
    if(this.head == null){
        return undefined;
    }
    else if(this.head == this.tail){
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.length--
    }
    else{
        let temp = this.head;
        let pre = this.head;
        while(temp.next){
            pre = temp;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        this.tail = pre;
        this.tail.next = null;
        this.length--
    }
```

I'm more concerned about the condition in which there's only one item inside the linked list.

Comment: There's only one path returning a value. A `.pop()` method usually is used within a `stack`-type collection and should remove and **return** the lastest added element

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine.

Here is a program that will test the implementation. Of course, the class needs to be completed with some other methods. The `return undefined` can be simplified to just `return`.

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value, next=null) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor(...values) {
        this.head = this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
        for (value of values) {
            this.push(value);
        }
    }
    push(value) {
        if (this.tail) {
            this.tail = this.tail.next = new Node(value);
        } else {
            this.head = this.tail = new Node(value);
        }
        this.length++;
    }
    pop(){
        if (this.head == null){
            return;
        }
        else if (this.head == this.tail){
            this.head = null;
            this.tail = null;
            this.length--
        }
        else {
            let temp = this.head;
            let pre = this.head;
            while(temp.next){
                pre = temp;
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            this.tail = pre;
            this.tail.next = null;
            this.length--
        }
    }
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let node = this.head; node; node = node.next) {
            yield node.value;
        }
    }
    consistent() {
        if (this.length != [...this].length) throw "length is inconsistent";
        if (this?.tail?.next) throw "tail is inconsistent";
    }
}

// Perform tests by doing the same operations on a native array simultaneously and comparing the result
let list = new LinkedList;
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    let choice = Math.random() > 0.5 && list.length < 10;
    let value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    if (choice) {
        list.push(value);
        arr.push(value);
    } else {
        list.pop();
        arr.pop();
    }
    list.consistent();
    if (JSON.stringify(arr) !== JSON.stringify([...list])) throw "Difference detected";
}
console.log("Tests done: all OK");
```

In JavaScript it is customary for `pop()` to return the value that was popped (this is not the case in every language, e.g. [C++](https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/pop_back/)), as this is how the native array prototype defines `pop`. So you might want to consider to apply the same principle on your `pop` method.

Here is a version of the above code that includes that feature (and tests it):

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value, next=null) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor(...values) {
        this.head = this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
        for (value of values) {
            this.push(value);
        }
    }
    push(value) {
        if (this.tail) {
            this.tail = this.tail.next = new Node(value);
        } else {
            this.head = this.tail = new Node(value);
        }
        this.length++;
    }
    pop() {
        if (this.head == null){
            return;
        }
        const value = this.tail.value;
        if (this.head == this.tail){
            this.head = null;
            this.tail = null;
        } else {
            let temp = this.head;
            let pre = this.head;
            while(temp.next){
                pre = temp;
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            this.tail = pre;
            this.tail.next = null;
        }
        this.length--;
        return value;
    }
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let node = this.head; node; node = node.next) {
            yield node.value;
        }
    }
    consistent() {
        if (this.length != [...this].length) throw "length is inconsistent";
        if (this?.tail?.next) throw "tail is inconsistent";
    }
}

let list = new LinkedList;
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    let choice = Math.random() > 0.5 && list.length < 10;
    let value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    if (choice) {
        list.push(value);
        arr.push(value);
    } else {
        if (list.pop() !== arr.pop()) throw "Inconsistent pop return value";
    }
    list.consistent();
    if (JSON.stringify(arr) !== JSON.stringify([...list])) throw "JSON is different";
}
console.log("tests done");
```

Answer (score -1):

In the case when there is only one item in the list, this might not work.

This piece of code will not run:

```
        while(temp.next){
            pre = temp;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
```

The length will be reduced. But i guess you will have to point both `this.head` and `this.tail` to `null`, in the case length is 1.

Comment: What @Cid mentioned is also correct. If you are implementing a `pop()`, there should be something you return. Something should be popped out

Comment: This part of the asker's code is not relevant when there is only one node in the list. In that case other parts of the code will execute; not this.

Comment: @trincot that is what i put right. That the code will NOT run. And in that case the user will have to mark both `tail` and `head` to null. You also wrote the same thing in your code

Comment: But the asker has already done that in their code. In your answer you suggest that this code is problematic ("might not work") as if the asker still has something to do ("But I guess you will have to..."). Neither is true, as the asker already took care of this.